# Can I use GetProcAdress to check which dll function is used in my process?

Tags: winapi, win32-process

Can I use `GetProcAdress` to check which dll function is used in my process?

I want to detect a specific function from a running dll in my process.

```
GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(TEXT("any.dll")), "AnyFunction");
```

If it returned not null, I can say this function used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetProcAddress` is actually checking if a specific function is **exported** in a specific DLL.

I guess what you want is to check if a specific function is **imported** in a specific DLL, AFAIK there is no API can do that, you have to manually parse the PE data yourself to get what you want.

---

Well, according to your new comment, you want to get which other DLLs are loaded through `LoadLibrary` at runtime, right?

If so, parsing the PE data is no longer sufficient for your requirements, what you need is to hook the `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress()` functions in your own process.

Answer (score 0):

`GetProcAddress` will find any function, used *or unused*, which is exported by a DLL which has been loaded into the process.

Also, it will not find used functions which were *not* exported.

So, depending on what you mean by "used", it may or may not suit your needs.

Comment: thank you for answer. is have any possible solution for my needs ?

Comment: It's not even clear, what you need. As explained in this answer, you'd have to explain, what *"used"* means to you. Though, really, you've probably asked for something you do not even need. This is called the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: ı load some dll in compile time for my exe. after that ı want check any dll load to my.exe with ntdll with LoadLibrary function in runtime

Comment: @KaanÇolak I have edited my answer to meet your requirements.

Comment: @kaa You cannot load a DLL at compile time. Whatever problem you are trying to solve, it appears that you don't know the target platform well enough to even understand that problem.